# how to point com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages to a package in a jar? Can we do that?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am developing a RESTfull web service project with jersey. my main modules are login, payment, etc. I created login and payment as different projects (RESTfull), Both these projects have webservices. And created ".jar" files.

Can we include these jar files in my main project and in web.xml, jersey configuration "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages" to the packages of these jars?
suppose my login project's package is "com.my.login" and my payment project's package is "com.my.payment"
can we do

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.my.login,com.my.payment</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Will it searches for Resources in these packages? 
If not, Is there any other way to implement this logic? I dont know is that a good/ bad doubt. Every answers will be thank full.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jersey 1.1 library

Then write it like this

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.my</param-value>
</init-param>
```

As com.my is the parent package of both. so it should include both package login and payment.